# How to establish isomorphism between kernel of linear functional and scalar field?

Tags: functional-analysis

So, I have to show that the kernel of a linear functional is a subspace of codimension one. Someone suggested to me that the following:

> If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ and $f\not\equiv 0$, then $\ker(f)$ is a subspace of codimension one and a subspace of codimension one is kernel of non-zero linear functional.

To prove this, we can do the following:

> $f$ induces an isomorphism between $X\backslash \ker(f)$ and $\mathbb{K}$. Conversely, if $Z$ is a hyperplane, let $g:X\rightarrow X\backslash Z$ be the natural map and let $T:X\backslash Z\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be an isomorphism. Then, $f=T\circ g$ is a linear functional on $X$ and $\ker(f)=Z$.

But my problem is: how do I establish those isomorphisms? Can somebody help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first isomorphism you are looking for is precisely the [first isomorphism theorem for modules](http://qu.edu.iq/el/pluginfile.php/62594/mod_resource/content/0/Module%20Theory%20-%20Lecture%203.pdf).

To check that $f=T\circ g$ is a linear functional you simply apply the definitions. Finally $x\in \ker f$ iff $T(g(x))=0$, but $T$ is an linear isomorphism so this occurs iff $g(x)=0$, but $g(x)=0$ iff $x\in Z$ by the definition of the natural quotient map.

If you were wondering how to construct $T$: By axiom of choice there exists a basis $\{e_i\}$ for a $Z$. We can append to that an element $e$ so that $\{e\}\cup \{e_i\}$ is a basis for $Z$. Define $T':X\to \mathbb K$ by extending $\alpha e\mapsto\alpha$ by Hahn-Banach. Define $T:X\backslash Z\to \mathbb K$ in the natural way from $T'$. I leave it to you to show that $T$ is an isomorphism. This is actually the standard way to show the converse.

Note we are assuming that $\dim X>1$ here, else the result is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define
$$\begin{align*}\tilde{f}: X\,/\,\mathrm{ker}(f) &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ [x] &\mapsto f(x).\end{align*}$$

You do need to show that $\tilde{f}$ is well defined.

To show that $\tilde{f}$ is an isomorphism, you just have to show that it is one-to-one and surjective. It is surjective because $f$ is not zero (so...?).

And it is one-to-one because $\tilde{f}([x]) = \tilde{f}([y])$ implies that $f(x) = f(y)$, and this implies that $f(x-y) = 0$. Therefore, $[x] = [y]$.

Now, for $T$, it is an isomorphism that exists and you simply took it for granted. Why does it exist (and not why it is an isomorphism) is the correct question. The answer should follow from the hypothesis that $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ has co-dimension $1$. And the answer depends on what "co-dimension $1$" means to you. :-)